# R apply a function on a subset of a data frame

Tags: r, apply

Went through a few posts on this topic, but couldn't find a solution. 
I have the following code using `apply()` to loop over the whole dataframe.

```
pclm <- data.frame(apply(B01001_AGE[6:23], 1, function(x){
    pclm <- pclm(x=seq(0,85,by=5), y=c(x), nlast=26, control = list(lambda = NA, deg = 3, kr = 1)) #nlast=26, assuming the oldest people alive are 110 years of age, 85+26=111.
    round(fitted(pclm))
  }))
```

but I want to loop over a subset based on the value of a column rather than the whole dataset.

For instance, I have a variable `sumlev`, I want to use my code for a subset when `sumlev=='050'`.

How could I do that without generating a subset of my dataset? Thanks.

Comment: I don't really follow how you wish to operate on a subset of your dataset without generating a subset of your dataset. Do you just want to use  `B01001_AGE[B01001_AGE$sumlev == '050', 6:23]` to `apply` against?

Comment: the only think I could think of is to use pipes but you still have to subset your data `df %>% subset(sumlev=='50') %>% apply(., 1, function(x))`

Comment: If I may ask, could you post a) a small example of your data, b) the function you want to apply (if that is pclm, which package is that from?), and the output that you expect to see?

Answer (score 1):

I suspect that you are asking how to apply a function to a subset without tearing your dataframes apart. Is that correct?

In that case, the answer is easy: you apply the function to the subset and reassign the return value to the subset of the dataframe. For instance, consider this:

Original:

```
mtcars[5:10, 2:3]
                  cyl  disp
Hornet Sportabout   8 360.0
Valiant             6 225.0
Duster 360          8 360.0
Merc 240D           4 146.7
Merc 230            4 140.8
Merc 280            6 167.6
```

Apply a function to the subset:

```
mtcars[5:10, 2:3] = t(apply(mtcars[5:10, 2:3], 1, function(x) x*x ))
```

Let's look at the subset:

```
mtcars[5:10, 2:3]
                  cyl      disp
Hornet Sportabout  64 129600.00
Valiant            36  50625.00
Duster 360         64 129600.00
Merc 240D          16  21520.89
Merc 230           16  19824.64
Merc 280           36  28089.76
```

If you are looking for simple ways of selecting rows based on a condition, consider this:

```
mask <- mtcars["carb"]>3
head(mtcars[mask,])
                     mpg cyl      disp  hp drat    wt  qsec vs am gear carb
Mazda RX4           21.0   6    160.00 110 3.90 2.620 16.46  0  1    4    4
Mazda RX4 Wag       21.0   6    160.00 110 3.90 2.875 17.02  0  1    4    4
Duster 360          14.3  64 129600.00 245 3.21 3.570 15.84  0  0    3    4
Merc 280            19.2  36  28089.76 123 3.92 3.440 18.30  1  0    4    4
Merc 280C           17.8   6    167.60 123 3.92 3.440 18.90  1  0    4    4
```

Comment: Thanks. your answer is the same as @thelatemail 's except that your answer is much longer lol

Comment: I think the difference is that thelatemail assumed you know how to reassign the output, I did not and have shown it to you. If this was not your question, it might be useful to clarify what exact problem you are facing.